# Prevent data to disappear when switching page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

So, I'm making this app where I need to fetch 3 different sets of data, "yesterday, today, tomorrow" and show them on different pages. The problem is that when I switch pages and go back the data is gone and I need to fetch it again and that is a waste of network recourse, I have searched a bit about this, and looks that the best way to save data and prevent it to disappear its to use Redux or localStorage. I'm using react Router. Any recommendation?

Comment: How do you store `"yesterday, today, tomorrow"` because this changes with each new day?

Comment: yeah that the only solution but redux there are so many package redux,zustand and recoil but there is still more explore it more

Comment: @mardubbles question is legit. If it's fetched dynamic data, why do you assume that it should not change on remount ?

Comment: you can use 'react-query', it provides query cache feature based on query keys. link to details https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options, but one common practice not mentioned yet is to use the cache. Many data fetching libraries has a build-in cache. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/swr as example. If this is not what you're looking for, perhaps someone else could benefit from this advice.

Answer (score -1):

Redux is a great option, however, there is no need to use it in simple projects.
The localStorage option is a very good one.

for example:

Read data:

```
const data = localStorage.getItem("fileName");
if (data) {
  setData(JSON.parse(data)); // or do anything you like with this data
}
```

Save data:

```
localStorage.setItem("fileName", JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
```

simple as it is...

Answer (score -1):

While both Redux and LocalStorage would work I would personally opt for react-query.
The result of the requests get cached avoiding unnecessary calls

https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview

Answer (score -1):

I know a lot of people may disagree, however for educational purposes if you want to learn how to use Redux, it may be worth checking out Redux-Toolkit - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

RTK has a few cool features whilst also allowing you to reduce boilerplate that you find inside redux.. RTK also supports SWR - Stale With Revalidation, essentially caching values, so you don't need to continue to fetch the data from the backend.

Give it a look, worth your while even just for educational purposes.